# Quiz with three or two answers in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to create a quiz where some questions have two or three correct answers.

I use `checkbox` and `foreach` but my code doesn't achieve my goal.

For example I answer 2 of 5 questions correct given counter must be 2 but it gives me zero.

**Here is my HTML part:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="res.php" method="get">

    <p>question</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="1">first<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="2">second<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="3">third<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="4">fourth<br>



    <p>question</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="1">first<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="2">second<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="3">third<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="4">fourth<br>



    <p>question</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="1">first<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="2">second<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="3">third<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="4">fourth<br>



    <p>question</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="1">first<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="2">second<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="3">third<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="4">fourth<br>



    <p>question</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="1">first<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="2">second<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="3">third<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="4">fourth<br>


    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Here is my PHP part:**

```
<?php

$q[0] = $_GET['q1'];
$q[1] = $_GET['q2'];
$q[2] = $_GET['q3'];
$q[3] = $_GET['q4'];
$q[4] = $_GET['q5'];

if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($q[0] as $item)
    {
        if (in_array(1, $item) && in_array(2, $item))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    foreach($q[1] as $item)
    {
        if (in_array(1, $item) && in_array(4, $item))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    foreach($q[2] as $item)
    {
        if (in_array(2, $item) && in_array(3, $item))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    foreach($q[3] as $item)
    {
        if (in_array(4, $item))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    foreach($q[4] as $item)
    {
        if (in_array(1, $item) && in_array(2, $item) && in_array(4, $item))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}


echo $counter;
?>
```

Comment: At each time `$key` is **either** 1 or 0 or some other value. `$key` cannot be 1 and 0 at the same time. So all your `&&`-logic doesn't work.

Comment: @u_mulder my questions have two correct answer how can i choose two correct answer ?

Comment: How do you understand that answer is correct?

Comment: @u_mulder ($key == 0 && $a5) && ($key == 1 && $a5) && ($key == 3 && $a5) with this !

Comment: In all your comments you have mentioned "Check if this is the first or fourth checkbox". So you are saying "or(||)" then using "and(&&)" in code below.

Comment: @mSatyam sorry see my question now !

Comment: I would like to know when counter value should increase when checkbox 1 and 4 both are ticked am i correct.

Comment: yes ! that's right  @mSatyam

Comment: why can't you explain your problem in detail?

Comment: your approach is not the right way, if I want to do quiz I will do it in database like mysql and code it in php correctly, maybe you get your code working in short term, but in longer term it is not usable.

Comment: @mSatyam question 1 checkbox 1 and 2 , question 2 checkbox 1 and 4 , question 3 checkbox 2 and 3 , question 4 checkbox 4 , question 5 checkbox 1 and 2 and 4 are correct . sorry for my bad English

Comment: see my answer now then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change I have made is in the HTML document. Here I have kept different value for each checkbox but same set of values are used in each group because using same set of values for option numbers in different questions doesn't harm and makes job easy when validating them. Below is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="res.php" method="get">

<p>question</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="1">first<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="2">second<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="3">third<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="4">fourth<br>



<p>question</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="1">first<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="2">second<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="3">third<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="4">fourth<br>



<p>question</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="1">first<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="2">second<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="3">third<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="4">fourth<br>



<p>question</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="1">first<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="2">second<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="3">third<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q4[]" value="4">fourth<br>



<p>question</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="1">first<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="2">second<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="3">third<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q5[]" value="4">fourth<br>


<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">

</body>
</html>
```

Added a function to check values what user has selected w.r.t what you have specified.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['q1']))
$q[] = $_GET['q1'];
if (isset($_GET['q2']))
$q[] = $_GET['q2'];
if (isset($_GET['q3']))
$q[] = $_GET['q3'];
if (isset($_GET['q4']))
$q[] = $_GET['q4'];
if (isset($_GET['q5']))
$q[] = $_GET['q5'];

// each questions correct answers list
$ans[] = array(1,2); // for q1
$ans[] = array(1,4);   // for q2 and so on...
$ans[] = array(2,3);
$ans[] = array(4);
$ans[] = array(1,2,4);

if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $counter = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($q); $i++)
    {
        if (check_answer($ans[$i], $q[$i]))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}

function check_answer($answer, $selected)
{
    $valid = true;
    foreach($answer as $a)
    {
        if (!in_array($a, $selected))
        {
            $valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

return $valid;
}

echo "Count: $counter";
?>
```

Note: You should do error checking too to handle bad scenarios.

Comment: each question have different answers . i use your code and update my question . take a look ! but doesn't work !

Comment: then in each iteration you match for those options.. according to your answers.

Comment: how can i prevent user to check all checkboxes ?

Comment: another question ! how can i show which checkboxes that user selected ?

Comment: If you just wanna show checkbox number that is already with you in q array just display or else if you wanna highlight it on the same page where checkboxes are present then again use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also using strings :

```
$answers[0] = $_POST['q1'];
$answers[1] = $_POST['q2'];
$answers[2] = $_POST['q3'];
$answers[3] = $_POST['q4'];
$answers[4] = $_POST['q5'];

$counter = 0;
$good_answers = ['12', '14', '23', '4', '124'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($answers); $i++){
    if(implode('', $answers[$i]) == $good_answers[$i]) $counter++;
}

echo $counter;
```

Hope that can help.